# How to convert Colored image into black and white using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, image, grayscale

I'm Using Visual studio 10.i want to convert colored image into a black and white?
i have tried to do following code it gets success but it takes lots of time to convert. can i do convert it without using anyloop in vb.net.
Thanks In Advance

```
Try
                        Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap((Image.FromFile("D:\\imgnam.jpg")))
                        Dim c As Color
                        Dim i As Integer = 0
                        Do While (i < img.Width)
                            Dim j As Integer = 0
                            Do While (j < img.Height)
                                c = img.GetPixel(i, j)
                                Dim r As Integer = 0
                                r = Convert.ToInt16(c.R)
                                Dim g As Integer = 0
                                g = Convert.ToInt16(c.G)
                                Dim b As Integer = 0
                                b = Convert.ToInt16(c.B)
                                Dim ans As Integer = ((r _
                                            + (g + b)) _
                                            / 3)
                                If (ans > 128) Then
                                    r = 255
                                    g = 255
                                    b = 255
                                Else
                                    r = 0
                                    g = 0
                                    b = 0
                                End If
                                c = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
                                img.SetPixel(i, j, c)
                                j = (j + 1)
                            Loop
                            i = (i + 1)
                        Loop

                        img.Save("D:\\imgnamNew.jpg")
                        Dim Bmp1 As New Image(Of Bgr, [Byte])("D:\\imgnamNew.jpg")
                        ImageFrame = Bmp1

Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Use a [ColorMatrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix(v=vs.110).aspx). See this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3772/ColorMatrix-Basics-Simple-Image-Color-Adjustment

Comment: Also you don't need double backslashes `\\ ` when declaring a path in Visual Basic. `D:\imgnamNew.jpg` will do just fine.

Comment: GreyScale (tag) is different than black and white (title), but yes, use ColorMatrix